# jQuery error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'backgroundColor' in undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation

```
$('.metro_menu_button').data('oldColor', $(this).css('background-color'));

$('.metro_menu_button').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: '#303030'
    }, 300);

}, function () {

    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: $(this).data('oldColor')
    }, 300);

});
```

As for title, the jQuery code above (which is performed on DOM ready) is returning this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for
>   'backgroundColor' in undefined

Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

---

I'm trying to do a button which, on hover, changes color and, when the mouse leaves, get back to its original color. I can't hardcode the values: I need this to be flexible and remember by itself the old background color. The following code works fine but, if I move the mouse in and out too quickly, it will "forget" the original color.

```
$('.metro_menu_button').hover(function () {

    $(this).data('oldColor', $(this).css('background-color'));

    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: '#303030'
    }, 300);

}, function () {

    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: $(this).data('oldColor')
    }, 300);

});
```

I need to save `oldColor` on DOMReady, not everytime the mouse gets in. In other words, I need to use the first code but this is throwing the error. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be able to use the 'each' function of jQuery:

```
$('.metro_menu_button').each(function() {
    $(this).data('oldColor', $(this).css('background-color'));
});
```

The 'each' should run this for each matching node; your original would probably not have had the correct value for 'this'.

Comment: thanks a lot, I thought the class selector was sufficient to perform the operation on all the elements: didn't considered the each loop.